# Python break out of exception statement and continue

Tags: python, exception, break

I am writing a script for an automated procedure. The test usses an SSH connection through Paramiko and for whatever reason (System related) the System Reboots and this closes the SSH connection. Python then throws an error saying the connection was forcibly closed.

I want the program to catch the error in an except statement, which will then restore the ssh connection, and then continue on from where it first hit the error.

The code is much too long to post but essentially I am looking to do the following:

```
 try:
      dotesting()
 except ParamikoError():
      restoressh()
      #here i want to break out and get back into dotesting()
```

I'm not sure this is possible given that "goto" is frowned upon and not available in Python. How would I got about executing this?

**EDIT**
So what I originally want to do is not possible. now Im shifting focus to restarting a specific step within `dotesting()`

```
 def dotesting():
      try:
            stepone()
      except ParamikoError():
            #Need to restart step here, want to flow into steptwo() below
      try:
            steptwo()
      except ParamikoError():
            #Need to restart step here, want to flow into the return statement below
      return("Success")
```

Comment: You can't get back to where the exception was raised, no. You can, at most, *restart* `dotesting()`. Just use a loop for that.

Comment: You'd otherwise have to refactor `dotesting()` to break out the steps you are running over SSH so that you can catch the exception at each step and and restart just that step.

Comment: @MartijnPieters This makes sense. I've updated the question to reflect the suggestion you've made as this could work for my case

Answer (score 0):

A really crappy answer is to write your program, and then save it as a list of strings, where each item in the list is a line of your program. Then do something like the following:

```
i =0
while i<len(program)
try: 
    eval(program[i])
    i+=1
except ParamikoError():
    pass
```

Like I said, very crappy solution, but I can't think of anything better.

Comment: Why strings? Why not function objects? Just put those in a list and call each one, passing in the ssh connection.

Answer (score 0):

If the exception is not thrown every time you should mock the ssh interface. Otherwise, you could do:

```
def stepone():
    raise AttributeError

def steptwo():
    return 1

class TestStuff(unittest.TestCase):

  def test_steps(self):
      with self.assertRaises(AttributeError):
          stepone()
      self.assertEquals(steptwo(), 1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```